# FB.Login "response.authResponse" with extended permissions, returns differently

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to work this one out for a little while now, and after much research haven't come to a clear conclusion.

Here is my code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log("permissions granted");
    } else {
        console.log("permissions not granted");
    }
}, {scope: 'email, publish_stream, user_birthday'});
```

When a fresh user enters the application, and the FB.login is fired on click they got a pop up window asking the user to "Log in" and requesting the Email and Birthday permissions.

If the user clicks cancel at this point we get the "permissions not granted" log.

If they click log in at this point, they are then shown another permission request for publish_stream.

If the user clicks cancel here they "permissions granted" log fires, despite the fact that not all the permissions in the scope have been granted.

If the user has clicked cancel, and then returns to the application and fires the FB.Login function again they are prompted to grant the publish_stream permission. If they click cancel this time the "permissions not granted" log fires.

Is this expected behavior? Why is Facebook acting differently on the two occasions? And if it is expected, how do I test that all permissions are granted and not just some the first time round?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is because its an extended permission. These are revokable. You can decline these as documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Edit:
You can see the permissions with the Graph API with [/me/permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/permissions)